# Cloudwatch Logs Subscription filter returns incomplete logs to lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a subscription filter created between a source_lambda and target_lambda. I encountered a problem where for one run of the source_lambda the logs(image_1) are being splitted into incomplete logs sent to target_lambda. Meaning that there are cases where some message are missing and also info like source_lambda's metadata are being sent later to the target_lambda.
Some example below of the payload(event) that the target_lambda receives.

Log from source_lambda below

```
 START RequestId: 04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010 Version: $LATEST
 2021-12-16T05:53:22.151Z   04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010    INFO    Retrieving object from s3 key: xx/xxxxx.csv
2021-12-16T05:53:23.103Z    04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010    INFO    Untransformed rows: 25577
2021-12-16T05:54:05.411Z    04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010    INFO    Transformed rows: 25577
2021-12-16T05:54:05.838Z    04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010    INFO    Sending an SNS notification
END RequestId: 04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010
REPORT RequestId: 04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010  Duration: 43746.31 ms   Billed Duration: 43747 ms   Memory Size: 2048 MB    Max Memory Used: 307 MB Init Duration: 487.33 ms
```

Payload sent to target_lambda for the above request_id at 2021-12-16T05:53:23.844Z

```
 [INFO] 2021-12-16T05:53:23.844Z    55671c02-135a-4f02-bf4c-42eaeb680167    Payload:{'messageType': 'DATA_MESSAGE', 'owner': 'xxxx', 'logGroup': '/aws/lambda/xxxx', 'logStream': '2021/12/16/[$LATEST]5f8f089166d746d0a402b4327a5e15ca', 'subscriptionFilters': ['ote-watchdog-LogInsightsLIVE002brandshelter-1USW5XJ7M7AFC'], 'logEvents': [{'id': '36565060100415049254496790935397288450170109850694320128', 'timestamp': 1639634002133, 'message': 'START RequestId: 04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010 Version: $LATEST\n'}, {'id': '36565060100816462668070342151944931379077780357801967617', 'timestamp': 1639634002151, 'message': '2021-12-16T05:53:22.151Z\t04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010\tINFO\tRetrieving object from s3 key: xx/xxxxxxx.csv\n'}]}
```

Payload sent to target_lambda for the above request_id at 2021-12-16T05:53:48.513Z

```
 [INFO] 2021-12-16T05:53:32.254Z    c0079a51-07a1-4ee0-9831-41c86a15ffc1    Payload:{'messageType': 'DATA_MESSAGE', 'owner': 'xxxx', 'logGroup': '/aws/lambda/xxxx', 'logStream': '2021/12/16/[$LATEST]5f8f089166d746d0a402b4327a5e15ca', 'subscriptionFilters': ['ote-watchdog-LogInsightsLIVE002brandshelter-1USW5XJ7M7AFC'], 'logEvents': [{'id': '36565060122046772097071495394414800827120771349538406400', 'timestamp': 1639634003103, 'message': '2021-12-16T05:53:23.103Z\t04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010\tINFO\tUntransformed rows: 25577\n'}]}
```

Payload sent to target_lambda for the above request_id at 2021-12-16T05:54:12.961Z

```
[INFO]  2021-12-16T05:54:14.569Z    bf8752f4-486d-47f1-aa28-a53f79be6556    Payload:{'messageType': 'DATA_MESSAGE', 'owner': 'xxxx', 'logGroup': '/aws/lambda/xxxx', 'logStream': '2021/12/16/[$LATEST]5f8f089166d746d0a402b4327a5e15ca', 'subscriptionFilters': ['ote-watchdog-LogInsightsLIVE002brandshelter-1USW5XJ7M7AFC'], 'logEvents': [{'id': '36565061065925812624880119911080623977988508723460505600', 'timestamp': 1639634045428, 'message': '2021-12-16T05:54:05.411Z\t04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010\tINFO\tTransformed rows: 25577\n'}, {'id': '36565061075091418901476206022251804188046985302418456577', 'timestamp': 1639634045839, 'message': '2021-12-16T05:54:05.838Z\t04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010\tINFO\tSending an SNS notification\n'}, {'id': '36565061076028050199814492194196304355498216485669634050', 'timestamp': 1639634045881, 'message': 'END RequestId: 04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010\n'}, {'id': '36565061076028050199814492194196304355498216485669634051', 'timestamp': 1639634045881, 'message': 'REPORT RequestId: 04daa904-61db-41b8-ab19-c761e6e07010\tDuration: 43746.31 ms\tBilled Duration: 43747 ms\tMemory Size: 2048 MB\tMax Memory Used: 307 MB\tInit Duration: 487.33 ms\t\n'}]}
```

As you can see the source_lambda's logs have been splitted into 3 events and sent to target_lambda

Additional_info:
Lambda retries=0
filter_pattern=" "

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.